# Anchor click not working with dynamic loading HTML in angular 8

Tags: html, angular, angular8

My issue is scrolling not working with dynamic loading HTML in angular 8, it loads the html, but if I click on a tag, it is not working with scrolling, please let me know if you any idea.

HTML Code are in separate file called a.html:

```
<a href="#immigrants">Immigrants</a>
<a href="#immigrants1">Immigrants1</a>
<a href="#immigrants2">Immigrants2</a>
<br /><br />
<h3 id="immigrants">Immigrants</h3>
<p> people who have temporarily or permanently settled in a country that is  different from their home country. </p>
<br /><br />
<h3 id="immigrants1">Immigrants1</h3>
<p> people who have temporarily or permanently settled in a country that is  different from their home country.</p>
<br /><br />
<h3 id="immigrants2">Immigrants2</h3>
<p> people who have temporarily or permanently settled in a country that is  different from their home country.</p>
```

In a.component.ts file, I called GET method on ngOnInit to get HTML so I received HTML as a string and I am displaying content using innerHtml such as.

```
let htmlCode='';
Call the GET API: this.http.get('./a.html', { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe((res)=>{
this.htmlCode=res;
});
```

```
<div [innerHtml]="htmlCode"></div>
```

Comment: You'll probably need to use the [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/guide/security#sanitization-example)

Comment: It is working, you save my time! Thank you Phix :)

Comment: Phix, I have a question, when I try to copy the link of the HTML page that I load with #id and paste it into new tab, it is not working i.e. http://localhost:4200/blog#immigrants1, any idea for this?

Comment: Define "not working". Is the page long enough for the scroll to affect the page?

Comment: Yes, it has too much content on this. Please try to browse the below link to check, 
It is working when a user clicks on a link in the page, but if the user tries to copy the link and paste in a new tab, it is not working, please check the below link
https://pumba.remitfinder.com/blog/remittance-all-you-need-to-know#remittanceImportance

Answer (score 0):

```js
 **JS**

function changeLoading() 
{
    $('body').append(
      '<div id="overlay">' + 
      '<button id="load">Carregando <span class="loading"></span></button>'+
      '</div>'
  );
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#overlay').remove();
    window.open( link );
  }, 2000); //2 seconds

}
```

```css
 **CSS**

  #overlay {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
#load {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -28px 0 0 -25px;
}
```

```html
 **HTML**

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxbeier.github.io/text-spinners/spinners.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="changeLoading();" type="button">
```